# Attempting to get attribute values in code returns incorrect values

Tags: android, android-layout

I wish to extract multiple attributes from a style resource (only interested in attributes that fall in the TextAppearance Group)

Style defined as so

```
<style name="Label" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/floatlabel_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

### First try

First I tried how TextView(lines 663-731) has it implemented, but then I found out we don't have access to *com.android.internal.R*

### Partial Solution

Which is why I switched to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913610/3922891

So I created textAppearanceAttr to replace com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance (only contains 10/13 TextAppearance attributes I am interested in)

```
int[] textAppearanceAttr = new int[]{    
        android.R.attr.textColor,
        android.R.attr.textSize,
        android.R.attr.typeface,
        android.R.attr.fontFamily,
        android.R.attr.textStyle,
        android.R.attr.textAllCaps,
        android.R.attr.shadowColor,
        android.R.attr.shadowDx,
        android.R.attr.shadowDy,
        android.R.attr.shadowRadius};
```

Here is how I used it. I get the style's resource id (resource is referenced by a clTextAppearance attribute)

```
   int ap = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomLabelLayout_clTextAppearance, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
   TypedArray appearance = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(ap, textAppearanceAttr);
```

And here is how I get the attributes (still following the answer at the above link):

```
    mLabelTextColor = appearance.getColorStateList(0);
    mLabelTextSize = appearance.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 15);
    mLabelTypeface = appearance.getInt(2, -1);
    mLabelFontFamily = appearance.getString(3);
    mLabelTextStyle = appearance.getInt(4, -1);
    (5 more...)
```

## Current Issue

It seems that only the **first** attribute gets set, every other either sets with the default or null.

#### A hack that seems to work

Individual arrays:

```
int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize};
int[] textStyleAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.textStyle};
```

And get attributes like so

```
    appearance.recycle();
    appearance = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(ap, textSizeAttr);
    mLabelTextSize = appearance.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 15);
    appearance.recycle();
    appearance = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(ap, textStyleAttr);
    mLabelTextStyle = appearance.getInt(0, -1);
    appearance.recycle();
```

Now doing this is such a waste.

### Questions

1. I would like to know why getting all the attributes at once doesn't work.
2. Is there a solution (where all the extra work is not necessary)?

**EDIT 1**

I found something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952929/3922891
And for some reason it works. Until I add more attributes to the array then everything becomes kerfuffle.

Example:

```
 int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.textColor,
            android.R.attr.textSize,
            android.R.attr.background,
            android.R.attr.textStyle,
            android.R.attr.textAppearance,
            android.R.attr.textColorLink,
            android.R.attr.orientation,
            android.R.attr.text};
```

If I get text using the above array it works.

```
String text = ta.getString(7);
```

But if I change the array to the below it fails (replaced android.R.attr.orientation with android.R.attr.shadowColor)

```
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.textColor,
            android.R.attr.textSize,
            android.R.attr.background,
            android.R.attr.textStyle,
            android.R.attr.textAppearance,
            android.R.attr.textColorLink,
            android.R.attr.shadowColor,
            android.R.attr.text};
```

Why is this happening? (Question #1)

Comment: Did you made sure that `a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomLabelLayout_clTextAppearance, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small)` effectively returns your `Label` style id (which is what i understand you'd like) ?

Comment: Yes it does return the correct id.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Make a test directly passing your style resource to make sure it's effectively caused by reading like this : `mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.Label, textAppearanceAttr)`.

Comment: It is correctly getting the resource because it does get the first attribute, for some reason anything after the first attribute doesn't work

Comment: I just tested your code and i have the same issue. I'll make another try

Answer (score 13):

I think I have an idea why it's happening. Looks like if IDs are not sorted, you get issues. `textColor` for example has the lowest `int` value, that's why it starts working being placed on the first position in the array.

If you take a look at `R.java` with your stylable, you'll see that android resource compiler has sorted the IDs for you. That's why it always works if you declare stylable in `attrs.xml` and may not work if you manually created the arrays of IDs.

I believe there is a performance reason for IDs to be sorted. If they are sorted then attributes can be read from the `AttributeSet` using one traversal instead of N traversals in case of N ids.

UPDATE:
I took a look at the source code and it proves my idea.
Context.obtainStyledAttributes() calls JNI method AssetManager.applyStyle(). 
You can find source here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp

On line 1001 you'll find a while loop where ix (index in the extracted XML attributes array) is always incremented and never reset to 0. This means if textColor is the last index in the array (variable "src" in the code) then we'll never get to that attribute.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @PrivatMamtora and @igret for investigating this! 
If the issue is that the ids must be ordered, this should be ok.

```
private static final int ATTR_PADDING = android.R.attr.padding;
private static final int ATTR_TEXT_COLOR = android.R.attr.textColor;
private static final int ATTR_TEXT_SIZE = android.R.attr.textSize;

private void loadAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    int[] ids = { ATTR_PADDING, ATTR_TEXT_COLOR, ATTR_TEXT_SIZE};
    Arrays.sort(ids); // just sort the array

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ids);
    try {
        padding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOf(ATTR_PADDING, ids), padding);
        textColor = a.getColor(indexOf(ATTR_TEXT_COLOR, ids), textColor);
        textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOf(ATTR_TEXT_SIZE, ids), textSize);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

private int indexOf(int id, int[] ids) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (ids[i] == id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("id " + id +  " not in ids"); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Get it working like this : i defined a new `styleable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>     
    <declare-styleable name="Label" >
        <attr name="android:textColor" />
        <attr name="android:textSize" />
        <attr name="android:textStyle" />
        <attr name="android:typeface" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then here's my styles.xml :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Label" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">#12345678</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

And finally the test :

```
public class TextAppearanceTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void test() {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.Label, R.styleable.Label);
        assertTrue(a.getColor(R.styleable.Label_android_textColor, -1) != -1);
        assertTrue(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.Label_android_textSize, -1) != -1);
        assertTrue(a.getInt(R.styleable.Label_android_typeface, -1) != -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not what I wanted to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more precise in why this does not fit your needs ?

Comment: I approve your way of doing it. It is a proper design. It does not require mucking around with indexes. But, I am trying to figure out what is going on in the TypedArray. Why does your method work? See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I don t understand either. Maybe there s somme aapt magic. Maybe comparing thé values obtained via attrs.XML with tour attr array will help ?

Comment: I have tried. I could not identify a pattern. There is one way it works, if you take the attr array and sort its contents, ascending, by resource Id, then it is able to work.

Comment: I expected something like that. Strange =)